# Spring MVC Trace Http Request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to disable the Trace verb on the serve so that endpoints are untraceable.

My endpoints are created using Spring MVC and there is a option `endpoints.trace.enabled=false.`

Pain is how to test this, if trace is disabled or not. I tried chrome plug-ins live HTTP Headers but it for generic site. I want to check my endpoint.

For example:

curl --insecure -v -X TRACE -H   http://localhost:8080/toy/49f6a7d3-eb20-3ab2-be3b-8399e7f28abf

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2015 04:34:03 GMT
< Content-Type: message/http; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 270
<
TRACE /toy/49f6a7d3-eb20-3ab2-be3b-8399e7f28abf HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I tried below but now it denies all the request.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE, "/**").denyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK TRACE is disabled by default on Tomcat, as well as Jetty 6,

You can use curl to make sure:

`curl -v -X TRACE http://www.example.com`

You want to see `405 method not allowed` in the response.

Comment: We are using jetty inbuild with Spring MVC.

Comment: It is not important for curl which application server or container you are using. Important part is you can see the response easily with this way which you want i guess.

Comment: @plzdontkillme you need to tell us what version of Jetty you are using. Don't be shy

Comment: Jetty version 9.2.9 which comes as a blessed version with Spring Boot 1.2.2 and Spring 4.1.5

Comment: @plzdontkillme does this help? https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/How+to+disable+the+request+method+Trace+in+the+Jetty+plugin+of+JobScheduler+to+avoid+XSS+exploits

Comment: I have update the question, i saw this link but we are using annotations so tried above code this didn't work either